# typescript commandline tsc -w acts like tsc -h

Tags: typescript, tsc

Could not find anything on webternet on this.
when typing tsc --watch it shows me the usage examples as if I typed tsc --help.
[image]

in addition (maybe it's related) when trying to explicitly compile a ts file, it screams about syntax error when there are none.

[image]

this is my tsconfig.json

[image]

Comment: what's your tsconfig like?

Comment: @toskv added to question